# Separate frontend from backend in Java App with docker containers

Tags: spring, docker

I am quite new in a Spring Framework and especially in Docker, anyway I want to improve my app in this way:

Currently I have an app with 2 containers: Database and App (based on tomcat). In the app container we have both: frontend (js files) and backend. During building app we create .war were frontend files are stored and during compose-up command, we copy those files as .war file to the app container (where tomcat works). Now I want to create another container for frontend to separate fronend from backend and in the future make the deployment process easier (so I want to have 3 containers: database, app and app-frontend). Is this goal achievable? The first idea which comes to my mind is to (with docker-compose) start up the app container and then copy frontend from the app-frontend to tomcat. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible.

So you want 3 containers

```
database, app and app-frontend
```

Your app already expose all your functionality by REST APIs.

And app-frontend calls those APIs.

So in other words you can just seperate your app-frontend and run it somewhere else 
in different container and it will work fine.

Few things you need to keep in mind and might face issue

1. Once you seperate app-frontend from your App you will get cross-origin issue. 
   As your API and app-frontend are not on same Address. So you might need to allow cross origin calls in your App
2. May be you need to change API calls path. If you are using jquery you might be using 
   url : "/userdetail". This will not work. You need to change it to  "url" : "IP:PORT/baseApp/userdetail"
3. app-frontend should be able to talk to app APIs.

**Edit 1:**

Answering your Queries

*1. How to build such app-frontend container?
Or 
My conception is wrong?*

Since you are going to use static files.

Just take those files and put them in any web server and if you have taken care of API urls.

You are done with building app-frontend container.

*2. Do I need something like nginx?*

You can use any web server like Nginx, Apache ... to deploy your app-frontend

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, probably I will have some problems with communication but I have some ideas about how to solve them. I am more confused about the actual separation. Because in all examples there is always API in one container and then front-end app with node.js and express or just angular/react. In my case I want to have only static js files in  `app-frontend` and during building containers just to copy them to `app container` where tomcat works. How to build such `app-frontend container`? Do I need something like nginx in `app-frontend container`? Or my conception is wrong?

Comment: added more detail